# Creating a unit test for the angular directive using Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am new to unit testing and would like to create a unit test suite for the angular directive that will set the focus of the form to the first invalid field.
Can someone provide me the unit test and this will help me learn Karma.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[focusInvalidInput]'
})
export class FocusFormDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  @HostListener('submit')
  onFormSubmit() {
    const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid');
    
    if (invalidControl) {
      invalidControl.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use your unit test to validate the input from the user?

I that case I don't think unit tests are a good solution (even if using a directive may be good). Unit tests are often used with mocked data in continuous integration flow (CI).

You should use a unit test to validate the good behavior of your form before deploying your solution - after a change in your app. Even if it's not related to your form to make sure you didn't break anything.

> Unit Testing is done during the development (coding phase) of an application by the developers. Unit Tests isolate a section of code and verify its correctness. A unit may be an individual function, method, procedure, module, or object.

Definition by [Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/unit-testing-guide.html)

See this answer : [How and when to use UNIT testing properly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89064/how-and-when-to-use-unit-testing-properly)

Comment: No. I want to unit test the function onFormSubmit()

Comment: Oh in that case I don't know how you could link `onFormSubmit()` with the rest of your app in a test - The goal of unit testing is to separate your method from the rest of the code to treat it individually